# Add rows together based on other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add rows together for specific values in column `Col2`.

Let's use the following dataframe:

```
  Col1 Col2 Value
0   A   1   1
1   A   2   1
2   B   1   2
3   B   2   2
4   B   3   3
```

Now I want to sum the rows with `Col2` equal to `1` and `2` and call it `1` while maintaining the groups in `Col1`. So I want to get this:

```
  Col1 Col2 Value
0   A   1   2
2   B   1   4
4   B   3   3
```

Is this possible with a general approach? I tried using groupby, but it does not seem to work. Note that I have multiple columns such as `Col1` and multiple `value` columns, so I hope to use a general solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) 2 by 1, then [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html):

```
(df.assign(Col2=df['Col2'].replace(2, 1))
   .groupby(['Col1', 'Col2'], as_index=False).sum()
)
```

Variant if you have several mappings to perform:

```
(df.replace({'Col2': {2: 1}})
   .groupby(['Col1', 'Col2'], as_index=False).sum()
)
```

Output:

```
  Col1  Col2  Value
0    A     1      2
1    B     1      4
2    B     3      3
```

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the values in "Col2" so that the `groupby` approach would work. Notice that once the values in "Col2" are replaced you can use the general approach with as many group columns and value columns you want.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create example data frame
ex_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Col1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
        'Col2': [1, 2, 1, 2, 3],
        'Value': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
    }
)

# Define mapping 
ex_map = {2: 1}

# Apply mapping to 'Col2' 
solution_df = ex_df.copy()
solution_df['Col2'].replace(ex_map, inplace = True)

# Sum grouping by 'Col1' and 'Col2'
solution_df = solution_df\
    .groupby(['Col1', 'Col2'])\
        .agg({'Value': sum})\
            .reset_index()

print(solution_df)
```